# PyRTF or phpRTF?

Tags: python, doc, php, rtf, office

Интересует реализация, а именно примеры на питоне или пыхе распаршивания РТФ или Дока от Мелкомфгких =).

**Update.**
Файлы содержат кирилицу! =).

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~sargie/RTF-Parser-1.09/lib/RTF/Parser.pm Правда это не питон и даже не пых.

Comment: вся печаль в том что он не работает с кириллицей :Р

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter Посмотрите это. А проще, вероятно, найти какой-нибудь конвертор rtf в xml (их много). А что за задача-то, если не секрет?

Comment: буду гуглить, а есть что-то *nix, а то C# опенсорц немного смешит =).

Comment: В стародавние времена Б. Тоботрас пользовался парсером на omnimark (1). Я не пытался смотреть вышеуказанную библиотеку у себя под linux -- лениво, но C# под mono у меня установлен. (2)

Возможно, Ваша задача и не требует полноценного разбора rtf (но это уже Вам решать)

Comment: @Дартаньян: а почему вас смешит opensource в сочетании с C#? Framework redist доступен бесплатно, компилятор тоже, даже бесплатные IDE есть (хотя строго говоря не нужны, вон gcc все с комстроки компилируют и ничего).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а вы понимаете, что doc, rtf и docx -- это таки 3 большие разницы, и, ртф не так уж сложно распарсить самостоятельно, а docx -- так вообще контейнер, внутри которого xml-ки лежат, если мне не изменяет память

Comment: Да, я прекрасно знаю разницу.

Comment: @actionless: вы уверены, что это у вас ответ, а не комментарий?

Comment: @Дартаньян: тогда вы должны понимать, что docx парсится теми же средствами, что обычная xml, а rtf в общем случае нормально парсится стандартными средствами, но можете еще попробовать pyRTF-next (или как-то так)

Comment: @VladD, в той же степени, насколько _подробно_ был поставлен вопрос..

Comment: Попробую либу но вы опять забыли суть вопроса в том что кирилица под ртф кодируется так что просто ее вычитать нет возможности.

Comment: ну если либа не поддерживает, то разбирайте потом кириллицу отдельно, не совсем понял, в чем проблема